# Is there an equivalent to The Federation in the Delta quadrant?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

The [United Federation of Planets](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/United_Federation_of_Planets) spanned thousands of light years and had over 150 member planets across the Alpha and Beta quadrants. For the purpose of this question, I'm considering the following to be important traits of the Federation.

- Territory (managed by a government or quasi-governmental group) spread across multiple planetary systems.
- Member planets willingly joined and contribute resources to the group. Members are from multiple species, each with their own original cultures and languages.
- Primarily interested in peaceful exploration, science, and free trade.
- Powerful: Technologically able to fend off any of their less-peaceful neighbors and defend their territory when necessary.

**With these qualities in mind, is there something resembling the Federation in the Delta quadrant, around the time of *Voyager*?**
I didn't watch all of *Voyager*, but the Delta quadrant always seemed like a vast and desolate wasteland, with independent systems here and there, and the occasional violent predatory group attacking them.

The part about "multiple species and cultures" is optional, but does speak to a Federation-like mentality of peaceful cooperation. Sadly I suspect the Borg have prevented most multi-planetary civilizations from growing too powerful.

Comment: "Member planets willingly joined" — that's what the Federation _wants_ you to think!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a word, no. Each of the regional powers that the Voyager encounters during its travels have at least one major feature that would cause them to be crossed off your list.

No society even comes close to Federation levels of cultural/societal diversity and interest in peaceful exploration.

- **Kazon Collective** - Primarily a single species that dominates less-advanced species within its borders.
- **Haakonian Order** - Antagonistic (to Talaxia) and uses WMDs to conquer enemy worlds.
- **The Swarm** - Xenophobic. Antagonistic to outside races
- **Vidiian Sodality**  - *Appears* to be a single race.
- **B'omar Sovereignty** - Xenophobic. *Largely* antagonistic to outside races
- **Krenim Imperium** - Xenophobic. *Largely* antagonistic to outside races.
- **Malon Cooperative** - *Appears* to be a single race.
- **Devore Imperium** - Xenophobic. *Largely* antagonistic to outside races. Antagonistic to telepathic races
- **Borg Collective** - Other member planets have not joined willingly.
- **The Hierarchy** - Xenophobic. Antagonistic to outside races
- **Hirogen** - Nomadic. Antagonistic (or indifferent) to outside races
- **Voth** - Antagonistic (or indifferent) to outside races.

[image]

Comment: Valorum, out of the Devore, B’omar, and Krenim, who do you think is most open to outsiders visiting, and who is least open to visitors?

Comment: @HamSandwich - The B'omar and the Devore are at least willing to negotiate passage through their territory, albeit neither encourage *casual* tourism. The Krenim aren't willing to accept anyone and are at war with all of their neighbours. (Side note. If you're a telepath, I'd pick the B'omar).

Comment: Shame, even the names sound threatening dictatorships. Except the Malon. They sound fairly cooperative. (stealing your earlier comment)

Comment: @zabeus - I presume they're cooperative *with each other*.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if the Devore tried to enter B’omar space, or vice versa. Or the Krenim did. I’d watch those episodes.

Comment: @HamSandwich - Since their respective spheres are relatively close, I'd assume they know about each other. I assume they'd be captured and questioned, then released or killed depending on the respective legal systems and the prevailing expediency. The B'omar (for example) were in the middle of a trade negotiation with another regional power when the Voyager arrived.

Comment: It would definitely be interesting to see one of those groups have their backs against the proverbial wall.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that although larger forces in the Delta quadrant can’t really be compared to the Federation due to how ideologically different they are, alliances and systems similar to how the Federation operates do exist. For example, the Kyrians and Vaskans. It could easily be argued that they had a similar ideology and philosophy to the Federation, perhaps even trying to copy its system (due to Voyager’s doctor telling them about it?), and just operated on a smaller scale than the Federation itself.

Criteria matches up pretty well:

Territory: Considering they have access to technology such as starships and holodecks, I’d say that they have gained control of a system or two, or at the very least, have the ability to.

Peoples and Cultures: Considering both species are unique and live peacefully with each other, I would say they aren’t very xenophobic. Combine that with the fact that they let a hologram with the appearance of a human become a medical leader in their world.

Peaceful or Not: From what they’ve seen, 700 years later after the “Voyager incident”, they seem to be pretty peaceful after the true details of Voyager were found. I hate to bring up the point about Voyager’s doctor becoming a medical leader on their home world again, but if he was willing to stay on their planet for a long time, they couldn’t have been all that violent, could they?

Powerful or Not: Again, they had starships and directed energy weapons, so they must’ve been able to defend themselves quite well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This is the start of an answer, but you should detail individually how each of those two match up with the criteria listed in the question; how much space do they control, do they comprise multiple species or cultures, how peaceful are they, how technologically advanced are they, etc.